# What must my Kendo datasource schema look like?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

given this json?

```
[
 { 
  "CompanyId":20,
  "CompanyName":"Walmart",
  "CompanyContacts":[
                     {
                      "CompanyId":20,
                      "FirstName":"Bob",
                      "LastName":"Green",
                      "Email":"bob@test.com",
                      "Phone":"1234567",
                      "IsActive":false
                     }
                    ]
 }
]
```

Comment: can you provide more information on what you are trying to do? Also, can you format the json document so that it's easier to read?

Comment: Why is this question being down voted? The answer below tells me exactly what I need to know. If you don't understand the question,move on, don't down vote it.

Comment: i don't know why it was downvoted. someone else did that prior to my comment, and prior to the question being answered.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The KendoUI datasource schema.Model does not currently support nested json or json with related entities.  It needs flat data.  Hopefully in the future the schema.Model will support mapping complex json to flat in the model definition.  However you can still use complex data in the grid you just can't define it in a schema.Model definition.

The mapping is actually done in the field definitions of the grid.
In addition see [schema docs](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#schema-object) you can parse your data using the schema.parse or schema.data functions to manually transform your nested data into flat data.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/delebash/uLkj9/3/) example with your data

```
{
    field : "CompanyContacts[0].FirstName",
    title: "First Name"
}
```

Also note, if you don't need parent record CompanyName and CompanyID since you have CompanyID in your CompanyContacts in the way your data is currently defined then you can use the data attribute of the schema to indicate the starting point of your records like so

```
schema : {
    model: mySchema,
    data: "CompanyContacts"
},
```

Comment: Many thanks - comprehensive answer. I will model the json to suit the datasource.

Comment: @GungFoo,  Yes, but that's ok.  Honestly I like the KendoUI framework but the docs and examples are very poor which is very not like the Telerik I am used to.  It took me awhile to figure out basic stuff like this because of the lack of good docs and examples so I felt his pain and gave him a helping hand  :)

Comment: @GungFoo - I hear what you are saying, but clearly I have attempted the binding, else how else would I have the json generated? Not quite the same as what you are insinuating. I have also got the datasource written as well as all the other parts of the grid. Its the binding bit that was giving me trouble and that's what I was asking for advise on. Please explain how that is asking someone to do my work?

Comment: why do people come on and insinuate stuff and be sarcastic, this is a help forum after all the bells and whistle. just move on if you've nothing to say. this question helped me out and was easier than finding something vaguely related in the docs.